# Height issue in iOS using sencha store filter

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Using sencha store filter, at very first time it will set height for dataview. After filtering, Its set to same height and i am getting tis height issue only with iOS not in android. Whether i have to set dynamic height or any global fix is there for iOS

```
_filterChange: function(sf, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var me = this;
    var MyStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    MyStore.clearFilter();
    var i=0;
    var MyStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    MyStore.filterBy(

        function(record) {
                stateID = record.get('STATE_ID');
            if (stateID === newValue) {
                console.log(i++);

              return record;
            } else {
                MyStore.clearFilter();
            }    


        });
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
    .myList .x-scroll-scroller{
     position:relative !important;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
     overflow-y:scroll !important;
     }
```